# ColumnViewerTooltipSupport in SWT

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

What is the exact use of `ColumnViewerTooltipSupport`? I know that it provides tooltip support for `ColumnViewers` but does it mean that it provides tooltip for treeViewers? How can I use this feature to provide tooltip support individually different tooltips for my each tree item when the mouse hovers over each item? Do I require a `MouseListener` for this or does the `ColumnViewerTooltipSupport` class provide it by default? Can someone please help me out here as I'm relatively new to SWT concepts.

My tooltip has multiple lines, How can I wrap the text and display it neatly? It seems like `ColumnViewerToolTipSupport` class does not wrap the tooltip text if the text is too long. I would like to use a tooltip window with a vertical scroll bar just like the InformationControl Windows in eclipse? If something like eclipse is not possible then just a tooltip window with wrapped up text.

Please show me an example snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ColumnViewerToolTipSupport` adds support for individual tooltips to `TableViewer` and `TreeViewer` (and other `ColumnViewer`s), you enable this using:

```java
ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(viewer);
```

The support expects that the label provider(s) for the viewer are based on `CellLabelProvider` (or one of its subclasses).

CellLabelProvider has `getToolTipImage`, `getToolTipText`, `getToolTipBackgroundColor`, `getToolTipForegroundColor`, `getToolTipFont` and `getToolTipShift` methods that you can override to control the tooltips.

Note: All this is `JFace` code not pure SWT

Comment: Do I need a Mouse Listener? I need the tooltip to be shown when the mouse hovers over each tree item.

Comment: Do I need a MouseListener when using ColumnViewerToolTipSupport class for the tooltip to be set when Mouse hovers over a tree item?

Comment: You don't need any listeners

Comment: My tooltip has multiple lines, How can I wrap the text and display it neatly? It seems like ColumnViewerToolTipSupport class does not wrap the tooltip text if the text is too long. I would like to use a tooltip window with a vertical scroll bar just like the InformationControl Windows in eclipse? If something like eclipse is not possible then just a tooltip window with wrapped up text.

Comment: I think you would have to subclass ColumnViewerToolTipSupport to override the createViewerToolTipContentArea to do that.