# How to display a tooltip when mouse is hovered on a list item?

Tags: java, swt

I want to display tooltip text whenever I hover the mouse on SWT List. When I was surfing on the internet, I found a listener `MouseTrackListner` and to override `mouseHover()` method.

But how will I get the text of the list when I hover on any item in the list?

Comment: Are you saying you want the tool tip to be different depending on the which list item is hovered over? This is a lot easier to do with `TableViewer` when you can use `ColumnViewerToolTipSupport`.

Comment: The thing is, SWT list is already implemented and i just have to add tooltip on top of that. I cannot add Tableviewer now as it may break some other implementations done on top of SWT List implemented.

Comment: I was able to add tooltip for each list item with the help of this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607768/get-the-item-in-the-swt-list-on-mouse-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SWT `List` does not have the concept of a tooltip per item. Only a tooltip for the entire control can be set. And the position of that tooltip is not related to the currently hovered over or selected item.

As [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) suggested, you should use a `TableViewer` and use the `ColumnViewerToolTipSupport`.

See here for more information about TableViewer tooltips: [ColumnViewerTooltipSupport in SWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105095/columnviewertooltipsupport-in-swt)